# Allow async method to be called only one instance at a time

Tags: c#, .net, locking, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a method which cannot be executed in multiple threads simultaneously (it writes to a file). I cannot use `lock`, because the method is `async`. How to avoid calling the method in another thread? Instead of calling it a second time, the program should wait for the previous call to complete (also asynchronously).

For example, create a new C# console application with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    internal class Program {

        private static void Main () {
            CallSlowStuff();
            CallSlowStuff();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async void CallSlowStuff () {
            try {
                await DoSlowStuff();
                Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static async Task DoSlowStuff () {
            using (File.Open("_", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    await Task.Factory.StartNew(Console.WriteLine, i);
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the second call to `CallSlowStuff` throws an exception, because it cannot access a file which is already opened. Adding `lock` is not an option, because `lock` and `async` don't mix. (`Main` method should be considered unchangable. In a real application, `CallSlowStuff` is an interface method which can be called anywhere.)

*Question:* How to make subsequent calls to `CallSlowStuff` wait for the currently running call to complete, without blocking the main thread? Can it be done using just async/await and tasks (and Rx maybe)?

Comment: BTW, do you really want to make your method `async void`? That's usually a bad idea, unless it's and event handler.

Comment: @svick "Async" chain of methods has to stop somewhere. If I make `CallSlowStuff` `async Task`, then I'll get compiler warnings in `Main` method. Do you have any suggestions how to completely avoid `async void`? Is it even possible? I was wondering about it, but didn't find any solutions.

Comment: That depends on the type of your application. If you really had a console application, the correct solution would be to synchronously `Wait()` for the returned `Task`. If it was a GUI app, then `async void` event handler would be the right solution. In ASP.NET MVC, the chain doesn't have to end, because controller method can return `Task`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need some sort of async lock. Stephen Toub has a whole [series of articles about building `async` synchronization primitives](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tag/coordination-data-structures/) (including [`AsyncLock`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/)). A version of `AsyncLock` is also contained in Stephen Cleary's [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

But probably a simpler solution would be to use the built-in [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805.aspx), which does support asynchronous waiting:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim SlowStuffSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private static async void CallSlowStuff () {
    await SlowStuffSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try {
        await DoSlowStuff();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally {
        SlowStuffSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. SemaphoreSlim solved my concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider altering the method body of `CallSlowStuff` to post messages to a [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228612.aspx) ActionBlock, and configuring it to a single degree of parallelism:

So keep a single ActionBlock somewhere:

```
ActionBlock actionBlock = 
    new ActionBlock<object>(
         (Func<object,Task>)CallActualSlowStuff,
         new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1});
```

Now:

```
public void CallSlowStuff()
{
    actionBlock.Post(null);
}

private async Task CallActualSlowStuff(object _)
{
    using (File.Open("_", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(Console.WriteLine, i);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Main` method is unchangable. Please read description after the example code.

Comment: @Athari, assuming you're looking for a queue of some sort, seems to me that that DataFlow would be appropriate here. Take a look at my revised answer.

Comment: While this would work, it feels like too complicated solution for something like this to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Semaphore in this instance, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Something like:

```
private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, 1);

private static async Task DoSlowStuff () {
  sem.WaitOne();
  // your stuff here
  sem.Release();
}
```

Comment: That would wait *synchronously*, which is a bad in an `async` method.